# Getting image for particular record in a table

Tags: servlets

I have a Student table in a database and it contains name, email and photo columns. I have stored information in the table and I want to display all the students' information in a table when I click a display button in my html page. I am able to get the data except photo So how can I get a photo of each student using servlets?

Comment: following should help http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/retreiveimage.shtml

Comment: `I am able to get the data except photo`,why?

Comment: Please provide additional details about how photos has been stored in database & how you are rendering it, code snippet will be helpful as well.